# Google + API Get Hangout Id from URL

Tags: google-api, google-plus, google-hangouts

I am trying to integrate Google Hangout API into my website.

The user wants to:

- Create a hangout
- Copy that URL
- Save that URL in our site
- Display information about hangout

I know that I can get the information I need using: https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/{activityId}

What I am struggling with is getting the activity id.

The only solution I see is:

- First somehow find the userid /plus/v1/people?query
- Then list the activities for that person /plus/v1/people/00000/activities/ and match the url
- Then call /plus/v1/activities/

There as to be an easier way surely!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easier solution would be to go a different route entirely. Instead of trying to get the hangout information via the Google+ post/activity, create a Hangout App that sends the URL for the hangout to your server. Under this scenario, the steps would be one of the two following scenarios.

Simple way:

- User starts a hangout video chat from your website
- The website link to create it also includes the gid of an app to start when the video chat starts
- The app sends a message to your website indicating the URL of the hangout that was started

Alternate way:

- User starts a hangout however they want to
- When they're ready to tell your website, they run the same app
- The app sends a message to your website indicating the URL of the hangout

Depending on your needs, you can then have the app do other things associated with monitoring the hangout is still alive, the number of people, etc. Your website would then display the information it receives using whatever format you wish.

You can find out more about this method in the video [How do I Include a Hangout on my Website?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Al4SbeVyLm4)